# Alerting about new post on particular Facebook profile?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, facebook

Is there any way to get informed as soon as some Facebook profile makes a new post? Any extensions like Check4Change can't work since, checking for everything, they also catch if someone became a new friend or liked some post. Instead, I'd like to be alerted if and only if the given profile makes a new post and as soon as it's published. Can this be done?

Comment: If you are looking for an addon to a browser, at least name it.

Comment: I use many browsers so any would suit me, be it for Chrome, Opera, Firefox or Safari.